# ¿Como agregar un where a una funcion que retona mas de un registro en POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, funciones

Tengo la siguiente función de salida, en donde me despliega más de un registro.

```
 create or replace function customerpayments_OUT
 (OUT out_institutioncode varchar, OUT out_idticket uuid,
 OUT out_status varchar)
 returns SETOF RECORD as
 $body$
 declare reg RECORD;
 begin
 for REG in select * from paymentrequest LOOP
    out_institutioncode := reg.institutioncode;
    out_idticket := reg.idticket;
    out_status := reg.status;
    return next;
    end loop;
    return;
end
$body$ language 'plpgsql'
```

Debido a que es una función únicamente de salida, no es necesario indicar ningún valor en la llamada

```
select * from customerpayments_OUT();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, deseo filtrarlos por un tipo de status y no hallo como implementar mi condición dentro de la función

Comment: Dato adicional: Cuando las preguntas son del tipo de base de datos, se recomienda incluir la estructura de la(s) tabla(s) que se relaciona(n) con la pregunta, asimismo, algunos datos de ejemplo. De este modo, es más fácil reproducir el escenario. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
SELECT * FROM customerpayments_OUT()
WHERE out_status = 'PAIDOUT';
```

Lectura sugerida:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/postgresql-create-function/